# MySQL combine two SELECT statements using AND

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to combine these two statements for two weeks already but to no avail. I've tried using UNION but it produces "the number of columns are different" error. Now I'm hoping to use AND clause to combine these statements. Thanks in advance :)

```
SELECT te_events.eventTitle,
       te_category.catDesc
FROM te_events
JOIN te_category ON te_events.catID=te_category.catID
ORDER BY te_events.eventTitle

SELECT eventStartDate,
       eventEndDate,
       eventPrice,
       eventDescription
FROM te_events
```

Comment: what your expected outcome?

Comment: What are you trying to achive by combining the two statements?

Comment: Could you add some sample data and a desired result? It's not at all clear to me what you want the query to produce.

Comment: In case of UNION or UNION ALL the selected columns must be same numbers in both queries.

Comment: For UNION and UNION ALL both queries have same number of columns with same corresponding data types.

Comment: I would like to produce a list of eventTitle, catDesc, eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventPrice, eventDescription in one query. The SQL if executed seperately works 100% fine, but I just need a way to combine the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT e.eventStartDate,
       e.eventEndDate,
       e.eventPrice,
       e.eventDescriptio,
       e.eventTitle,
       c.catDesc
FROM te_events AS e
LEFT JOIN te_category AS c ON e.catID=c.catID
ORDER BY e.eventTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?:

```
SELECT te_events.eventTitle,
       te_events.eventStartDate,
       te_events.eventEndDate,
       te_events.eventPrice,
       te_events.eventDescription,
       te_category.catDesc
FROM te_events
JOIN te_category ON te_events.catID=te_category.catID
ORDER BY te_events.eventTitle
```